# What is the significance of "twelve" in "worth twelve of"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

> “You’re **worth twelve of** Malfoy,” Harry said.

This is a sentence from *Harry Potter I*, where Harry said this to Neville.

My question is what is actually meant by saying this. Is there any significance of *twelve* ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number 12 (a dozen) is a very old and established unit of measurement in English, and presumably in other languages too. A jury comprises 12 people too.

Harry could have said "a dozen ..." with the same effect as 12, since they both have a familiar resonance with the culture that eight, eleven, 14, 17, etc do not have. Even ten has probably slightly less resonance, but I expect the author could have used it equally.

Comment: Yes you might be right!

Comment: Don't forget that [twelve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_(number)#In_religion_and_mythology) is a number that is significant in *many* cultures and traditions. In this case, it is most likely the western/Christian/biblical context.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't read the book so I can't say if there's greater significance in the specific context.

But in general, it's fairly common to say, "Al is twice the man that Bob is" or "Sally does five times as much work as Jane", with no intention that the number refers to any real measurement.

The actual number chosen, whether 2 or 10 or 12 or 1000, doesn't real mean anything, except to give a general idea of the magnitude that you're talking about. If you said "Al is worth 100 times Bob", you are saying there is a huge difference, probably more than if you said "Al is worth twice as much as Bob". But it would be very unlikely for someone to say "47 times" or "fourteen point seven three times". Such precision would only be meaningful if there was some real quantity being measured, like if we were comparing Al to Bob by the number of widgets that each could build in an hour or some such.

Unless the number 12 has specific meaning in this book, it could probably have just as well said "you're worth ten of Mallory" or "you're worth fifteen of Mallory" and there would be no difference in meaning.

Comment: Exactly. I think the last couple of lines are spot on

Answer (score 2):

It would be a lot stranger if he said "eleven" or "twenty six." Twelve (a dozen) is a very common number: the year consists of twelve months; there were twelve Apostles; there are twelve hours in a day according to some clocks; twelve school grades; twelve players per soccer team if you count the goalie; twelve bars to a blues progression. The book is the best ever written. All other world literature pales by comparison. The author should be canonized. A petition to that end is already being composed at the highest level and will be sent to the Pope at the first available opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

This might simply imply that Neville is 12 times the man that Malfoy ever was.

Comment: That's clear. But why 12! Is that randomly used?

Comment: I believe he just used a random number. But 12 may have significance in the story. If you suspect something like that, you should ask the die-hard Harry Potter fans in this community of stack exchange. Maybe they can clarify your doubt regarding the integer. Just ask the same question and tag it with "Harry Potter".  

http://scifi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Till now I've not found any relevance of 12 in the story. Anyway thank you.

Comment: I think its just a random number Potter used. Anyways, good hunting my friend.

Comment: Absolutely not random: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_(number)#In_religion_and_mythology

Comment: @Stephie Plenty of numbers have cross-cultural significance: three, seven, forty, and so on. There's no reason it *has* to be twelve here unless it has significance within the Rowlingverse.

Comment: @choster, true, but it is a number with significance (like those you mentioned), not *just random number* as the answerer adamantly states in his comments.

Comment: @Stephie But it *is* a random number; there's no evidence Rowling chose twelve *because* it has other cultural significance— that seems to be entirely coincidental, especially since her works do not have strong numerological themes.

Comment: @choster Apart from the cultural context she grew up in. But this discussion is futile.